# Is there a way to find all users with disabled passwords on redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

I'm trying to find all users that have been created with 'disabled' passwords in redshift. We are looking to maintain users syncing from ldap. They will be created with disabled passwords so they cannot log in directly and we want to list them so they can be removed when longer required.

```
create user no_pass_user with password disable
```

I've tried querying pg_user where passwd is null etc, but nothing

```
select * from pg_user where passwd is null or passwd = 'disable' or passwd = '' ;
```

I could use expiry date etc, but would prefer disabled password if possible.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, did you ever find an answer to this one ?
Thanks